# WKWebView detect Angular / React JavaScript page load?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, uiwebview, wkwebview

I'm building an application which contains a WKWebView and trying to detect when the user navigates between pages. The WKNavigationDelegate works fine for plain old HTML sites with links, but fancy new Angular/React sites slip right past it. Is there any way to detect this?

Comment: Did you ever get it to work?